# EntityName enumeration

Tags: c#, enums, entity, dynamics-crm-2011

In order to do queries to Microsoft Dynamics CRM, certain entity names must be passed to filter the results. However, using .NET Framework 4, I don't have the EntityName enumeration, although it should be public. Why is that?

These are the enums I miss: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959317.aspx

Comment: I do not have this issue. What version of microsoft.crm.sdktypeproxy are you referencing?

Comment: Version 5, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deprecated in CRM 2011. From the SDK:

> In earlier versions of Microsoft Dynamics CRM had an enumeration called EntityName that represented the entity type code for each entity. For Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011, these two values have been changed to constants on each entity class.

See SDK topic "Summary of Changes Between Versions"

(The example you gave was from the CRM 4.0 SDK)

Comment: So, what should one use instead of *EntityName*? I've googled it a bit but can't find anything useful. Up to now, I just hard-coded the entity's logical name using a string like this: `LogicalName = "account"`. Then I discovered the different syntax. **Then** I discovered that it's deprecated.

Comment: In fact, I found it appropriate to start a new question. If you're so kind and take a look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315073/what-should-be-used-instead-of-the-deprecated-entityname-account-tostring), I'd be delighted to get your (or any) input.