# What should be used instead of the deprecated EntityName.account.ToString()?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, query-expressions

When I design a *QueryExpression*, I've always used the following, hard-coded syntax.

```
QueryExpression expression = new QueryExpression
{
  EntityName = "account";
  ...
}
```

In [this blog](http://www.langalaxy.de/2009/07/howto-retrieve-members-of-a-marketing-list/) the following syntax based on [this enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959317.aspx) is used.

```
QueryExpression expression = new QueryExpression
{
  EntityName = EntityName.account.ToString();
  ...
}
```

I liked it much better but I couldn't find it using intellisense. Then I've found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914575/entityname-enumeration) where it's explained that the syntax is deprecated.

So, what should one use instead of *EntityName*? I've googled it a bit but can't find anything useful. It seems to me that some kind of enumeration is to be preferred before the hard-coded expression. Is that correct? And if so, how to do that in CRM 2011?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if you are using late bound entities you can use [Entity.LogicalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entity.logicalname.aspx).

Comment: That's valid once I have the entity instance. What can be used if I'd like to get the logical name of an entity and don't want to type it? Suppose I forgot that *marketing lists'* schema name is simply *list* (or maybe I'm unsure if it's capitalized or not). I can just look it up or give it a try and correct the error but I'd like to learn a more professional method to achieve that. Should I not think about it **that** way (especially since I'm using late bound)?

Comment: Well you could query the CRM metadata services to get the name, however this adds a web service call. Also given your example, you then have to remember `marketing list` to get `list`, which is basically the same problem. At some point you will have to remember a reference to the entity in CRM, as the schema name is the one you want it might as well be that. Usually I just hardcode all my entity names either as literal strings or in a readonly variable.

Comment: Good point. I was most thinking that it'd be convenient to get intellisense for it. Being lazy, hehe...

Comment: Well if you store all the names in static variables you can use intellisense then.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [early bound classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328210.aspx) you could use following syntax also for your custom entities. If not, this will work for all standard entities.

```
Account.EntityLogicalName
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write for example  Contact.EntityLogicalName.ToString() but you in this case you must

use early bound classes